# Why ACRA doesn't send crash reports to my HTTP server?

Tags: android, acra

I have two devices with different Android OS versions 8.1 and 9.
I granted all permissions for applications on both devices.
But behavior differs.

This is output related to the unworking case. The report doesn't send.

> E/ACRA: ACRA caught a ArithmeticException for
>   com.example.root.photolist2
>       java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
>           at com.example.root.photolist2.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:903)
>           at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3608)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:436)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:196)
>           at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:888)
>           at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
>           at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
>           at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
>           at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
>           at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1192)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3184)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4182)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3896)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.onTouchEvent(DropDownListView.java:217)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView.onTouchEvent(MenuPopupWindow.java:129)
>           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12531)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3026)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2705)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3032)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3032)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
>           at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PopupWindow.java:2407)
>           at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12772)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5230)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5030)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4545)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4564)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4704)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4572)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4761)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4545)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4564)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4572)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4545)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7263)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7232)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7193)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7369)
>           at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:247)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) I/Toast:
>   Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.root.photolist2,
>   PackageName:com.example.root.photolist2 W/MessageQueue: Handler
>   (android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate)
>   {37967e2} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate)
>   {37967e2} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:549)
>           at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:745)
>           at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:697)
>           at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:667)
>           at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:604)
>           at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate.sendDisplayEvent(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:619)
>           at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal.handleDisplayEvent(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:278)
>           at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal.access$100(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:51)
>           at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayManagerCallback.onDisplayEvent(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:605)
>           at android.hardware.display.IDisplayManagerCallback$Stub.onTransact(IDisplayManagerCallback.java:54)
>           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:735) I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13634 SIG: 9 Process 13634 terminated.

The report has sent normal (android 8.1).

```
E/ACRA: ACRA caught a ArithmeticException for com.example.root.photolist2
    java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
        at com.example.root.photolist2.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:903)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3464)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:436)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:196)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:888)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1158)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3127)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4054)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3813)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.onTouchEvent(DropDownListView.java:217)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView.onTouchEvent(MenuPopupWindow.java:129)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11808)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3016)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2666)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3022)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3022)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2680)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PopupWindow.java:2406)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12052)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5066)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4876)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4408)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4461)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4427)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4554)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4435)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4611)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4408)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4461)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4427)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4435)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4408)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7002)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6976)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6933)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7120)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: android.widget.LinearLayout{c201542 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@9729d3
D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7bf8bbd000)
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7bf8bbd000,api=1)
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24846 SIG: 9
Process 24846 terminated.
```

Any ideas?

My Application class attached bellow:

```
@AcraCore(reportFormat = StringFormat.JSON)
@AcraHttpSender(
        uri = "http://XXXXXXX.ca:6127/acrarium/report",
        basicAuthLogin = "abcdef",
        basicAuthPassword = "123456",
        httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST)

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Parse SDK stuff goes here
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        //ACRA.init(this);


        CoreConfigurationBuilder builder = new CoreConfigurationBuilder(this);
        builder.setBuildConfigClass(BuildConfig.class).setReportFormat(StringFormat.JSON);
        builder.getPluginConfigurationBuilder(ToastConfigurationBuilder.class).setEnabled(true);
        builder.getPluginConfigurationBuilder(ToastConfigurationBuilder.class).setResText(R.string.acra_toast_text);

        ACRA.init(this, builder);


    }
}
```

Comment: http or https endpoint?

Comment: I set up to HTTP point. http://XXXXXXX.ca:6127/acrarium/report And I use the Acrarium. All together it worked fine before I have bought a new phone and tried it...

Comment: android 9 doesn't allow calls to http endpoints unless you explicitly configure it to

Comment: I have changed my code but the issue is continuing. I add base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" and  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: And I have tried to send reports via email. @AcraToast(resText=R.string.acra_toast_text, length = Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
@AcraCore(buildConfigClass = BuildConfig.class)
@AcraMailSender(mailTo = "XXXX@gmail.com"). It doesn't work either.